# Hacer aparecer o desaparecer el texto que tiene un button en un Label

Tags: c#

Quiero que, al pasar el mouse por encima de un botón, me muestre el texto de este en un Label y al quitar el cursor del botón el texto desaparezca.

ya logré mostrar el texto, pero no logro desaparecerlo.

De esta manera muestro el Texto del Botón en el Label:

```
private void btnarchivos_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (panelMenu.Width == 56)
    {
        lbltitulos.Text = "| " + btnarchivos.Text;
        lbltitulos.ForeColor = Color.SteelBlue;
    }
}
```

gracias de antemano.

Comment: Pero que es esto...winforms, wpf, uwp....etc????

Comment: Hola, la Comunidad agradeceria que si alguna de las respuestas dadas en tu pregunta es correcta o te ayudo a solucionar tu problema, marques estas como respondida, adicional esto te dara resputacion como usuario y en tu cuenta.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el evento [MouseLeave](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.mouseleave?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) para que cuando el puntero del mouse salga del área el botón se llame este método y tu eliminas el texto de `lbltitulos` :

```
private void btnarchivos_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    lbltitulos.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, de esta forma también funciona correctamente

Answer (score 0):

Si queres que el texto desaparezca del Label cuando se quite el cursor del botón, puedes utilizar el evento MouseLeave del botón. Aquí te muestro cómo hacerlo:

```
private void btnarchivos_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (panelMenu.Width == 56)
    {
        lbltitulos.Text = "| " + btnarchivos.Text;
        lbltitulos.ForeColor = Color.SteelBlue;
    }
}

private void btnarchivos_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbltitulos.Text = ""; // Limpiar el texto del Label
}
```

El evento MouseLeave se activará cuando el cursor salga del área del botón. En este evento, simplemente asignas una cadena vacía al Text del Label, lo que hará que el texto desaparezca cuando el cursor se quite del botón.

Con esta implementación, el texto se mostrará en el Label cuando pases el mouse por encima del botón y desaparecerá cuando quites el cursor del botón.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, te sugerimos revisar [answer], recuerda dar crédito correspondiente para evitar "plagio".

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta compañero, me ayudo a resolver mi requerimiento